# Convert two array in one multidimensional

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two array :

```
a = [a,b,c,d]
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

And I would like to convert in this

```
c = [[a,1], [b,2],[c,3],[d,4]]
```

I tried `a << b` but this does not work, any idea how to convert this ?

Comment: Your arrays, both input and output, are not valid [tag:ruby].

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```rb
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a.zip(b) # => [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3], ["d", 4]]
```

Comment: ...or `[a,b].transpose`.